# ASP.NET MVC ValidationMessage not showing for dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have set a `Required` `Validationmessage` for the `Role` field in the `ViewModel`. The `dropdownlist` supposedly reflects the `Role` field in the `ViewModel`. However, when I did not select any values from the `dropdownlist`, it does not show any error at all even though I already set the `Required` validation for that field..any idea why?

**The ViewModel:**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a user type")]
    [Display(Name = "Select user type:")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
 }
```

**The View:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Role, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Role", null, "Select user type", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("Role")
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Does your request hit controller's action and can you please inspect sate of your model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get client side validation when you use an overload of `DropDownList()` when the first parameter is `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (i.e when using the same name for the `SelectList` as the property your binding to). If you inspect the html your generating, you will see that there are no `data-val-*` attributes generated for the `<select>` element.

It would work using if you were to use (say)

```
ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(...);
```

in the controller and

```
@Html.DropDownList("Role", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>),ViewBag.RoleList "Select user type", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

in the view, however since you have a view model (which is best practice), then add a property for the `SelectList` to the model

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    ....
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a user type")]
    [Display(Name = "Select user type:")]
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
 }
```

and in the GET method, populate the collection before you pass the model to the view

```
RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel()
{
    RoleList = .... // your query to generate the SelectList
};
return View(model);
```

and in the view, use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Role, Model.RoleList "Select user type", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Role)
```

Refer also [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OxriS9) for further examples of why the property your binding to and the name of the `ViewBag` for the `SelectList` should not be the same.

Comment: I got your idea, however I don't know how to populate the ``IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RoleList`` from a db context. Any help is appreciated!